Plus or minus sign for exponents
I was solving an equation and I stumbled upon this condition:
$$\log_2(x)\neq\pm1$$
Which solves in $$x\neq2 \hspace{0.2cm} \wedge \hspace{0.2cm} x\neq \dfrac{1}{2}$$
My question is:
can I simply write it as
$$x\neq2^{\pm 1}$$
I have never seen it but it looks so concise and simple that it looks right

I would be very puzzled by that expression, out of context.  I'd just write $x\not \in {2,\frac 12}$.

Seems reasonable, but may be confusing to readers who are accustomed to seeing statements like $~r = \pm s,~$ but are not accustomed to seeing statements like $~r \neq \pm s.~$  Better to write it out, to avoid possible confusion for the reader.

Best avoid ambiguous abuses of notation.  In my opinion $A = \pm 1$ as a shorthand for $A=1$ or $A=-1$ is understandable but $A\ne \pm 1$ seems an unacceptable stretch through a negation.  And either of them are only acceptable as a final solution; neither should be an initial declaration to be further solved. And althought $a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$ is acceptable and clear $2^{\pm 1}$ looks just weird and wrong to me.  BUT that's utterly subjective and I can't really argue we my interpretation is okay up to but not beyond an imaginary line. And I can t say yours is "wrong".

Okay so the problems arise with the $\neq$ sign right? I am honestly kind of used to notations like $x \neq \pm a$ but I guess this is really subjective
